# Why I am not getting the state in BlocBuilder when I emit it in BlocProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am working on the application and emitting the states for particular cubit in the main file in the "MultiBlocProvider" like this.

```
return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<Cubit1>(
          create: (context) {
            Cubit1 cubit = Cubit1(Cubit1State());
            cubit.fetchData1FromApi();
            return cubit;
          },
        ),
        BlocProvider<Cubit2>(
          create: (context) {
            Cubit2 cubit = Cubit2(Cubit2State());
            cubit.fetchData2FromApi();
            return cubit;
          },
        ),
]
```

and in my cubit, I declared these functions like this.

```
 fetchData1FromApi() async {
    final data = await _state.api.retrieveData(0,maxValue);
    emit(DataState(data));
  }
```

Now, purpose of this code is that whenever application starts, it first fetch data in the main file so that we can use that data and do not need to use FutureBuilder. However, I am not getting the state when application starts. I wrote same code for HydratedBloc and it is working. I think, it should also work. Any clue? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

If the cubits/blocs are not used (e.g. by a BlocBuilder or BlocListener that has been called in a Widget for those cubits/blocs), the cubits/blocs are never created. I.e. the create callback is never run. Check that first.

There is a property on the BlocProvider, `lazy:`, that can be set to false. This determines whether the bloc/cubit should be created lazily. Defaults to true. You can change this to false, making sure that the cubits/blocs are created by the BlocProvider right away.

For simplicity, I'd also use the cascade notation to streamline the create calls as follows:

```
BlocProvider<Cubit1>(
   create: (context) => Cubit1(Cubit1State())..fetchData1FromApi()
),
BlocProvider<Cubit2>(
   create: (context) => Cubit2(Cubit2State())..fetchData2FromApi()
)
```

Comment: Using streamline notation, I am getting an error "Exception has occurred.
UnimplementedError". I also think that I need to use StreamBuilder. Putting lazy:false gives another error "_TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type Cubit".

Comment: "Exception has occurred. UnimplementedError" comes from somewhere else. StreamBuilder have nothing to with this. Are you using two periods (`..`) ? Sounds like you use one and just calling the method on the cubit?

Comment: Yes, I tested both. First with two periods(..) and without lazy. With that I got an exception "UnimplementedError". Second with lazy: false with one period(.) and got another error. Also note that I am not Future<void> with api call function. I will edit my question.

Comment: You can never do with one period there. It has to be cascade notation, i.e. two periods. So go back to the first thing you tried. And find out where the Uninmplemented error comes from, because this is not the cause of it.

Comment: With HydratedBloc, it works because it creates a cache and use cache even data is not retrieved.  Similarly, it works with Firebase because that also creates a cache.

Comment: Okay, I tried again with two periods(..) and lazy:false and got an exception "UnimplementedError".

Comment: Figure out where the exception comes from, and solve that. You don't need to create a cache. Just make sure that your cubit have different states for when the data is retrieved and not, so that the UI can react accordingly.

Comment: No clue, why I am getting an exception "UnimplementedError". Getting it before function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that when we fetch api data within main file, it takes time to fetch the data. Before that operation is completed, it shows the first page/screen of application. As, I am retrieving data from private API and database and not using firebase, there I need cache if I want to retrieve data  in the main file and if I do not want to use FutureBuilders because of too many states. Simple solution is to use HydratedCubit because then api is called through it and it always have some data stored. HydratedCubit uses Hive but you can also create your DB using Hive, if you do not want to use Hydrated Cubit and then can use simple Cubit. I am writing simple HydratedCubit below:

```
class Cubit1 extends HydratedCubit<Cubit1ApiState> {
  Cubit1(Cubit1ApiState state) : super(state);

  fetchData() async {
    final data = await _state.api.retrieveData(0, maxValue);
    emit(Data1State(data));
  }

  @override
  Data1ApiState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    try {
      final state = Data1State(DataType.fromJson(json));
      return state;
    } catch (_) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(Data1ApiState state) {
    if (state is Data1State) {
      return state.data.toJson();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

abstract class Data1ApiState extends Equatable {}

class Data1InitialState extends Data1ApiState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class Data1State extends Data1InitialState {
  Data1State(this.data);
  final DataType data;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data];
}
```

Now, you can fetch data in the main MultiBlocProvider like this.

```
return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<Cubit1>(
          create: (context) {
            Cubit1 cubit = Cubit1(Data1InitialState());
            cubit.fetchData();
            return cubit;
          },
      ),
]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think if you use bloc in the correct way, your problem maybe solve.
you should use Event for eh bloc for fetch Api or other work

```
Scaffold(
       appBar: getAppBarWidget('appBar', []),
      body: MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => FinishBloc()..add(InitialFinishEvent())),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => SendTourInfoCubit(),
      ], child: const BodyContent()),
    );
  }
```